# powerpoint doesn't wait for mouse click in animation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Сразу идет вся анимация подряд. Задержать её не получается. везде стоят "по щелчку", но программа игнорирует задержки.
Причем презентация создавалась на 2019 версии на работе. Дома на 2016 проверяю. Тоже самое.

Google Trans

> **powerpoint doesn't wait for mouse click in animation**
>
> All the animation happens at once. It's impossible to stop her. everywhere they are “on click”, but the program ignores delays. Moreover, the presentation was created on the 2019 version at work. I'm checking at home for 2016. The same.